# Method named "*" cause compile error

Tags: scala, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I'm little confused about this code:

```
abstract class Abstract3 {   
    type TP
    protected def action(arg: TP): TP   
    def *[T <% TP](arg: T) = action(arg) 
}

class Concrete3(str: String) extends Abstract3 {   
    type TP = Concrete3 
    override protected def action(arg: TP) = new TP("") 
}

class Test3 {   
    implicit def str2Concrete(s: String)(implicit num: Int) = new Concrete3(s)   
    implicit val a = 1
    val foo = "AA" * "BB" * "CC" 
}
```

Scala compiler does not compile it, with an error message:

> test.scala:15: error: value * is not a member of String   val foo =
>   "AA" * "BB" * "CC"
>                    ^ one error found

But if we change ''*'' to '/' or anything else, it will compile successfully:

```
abstract class Abstract3 {
  type TP
  protected def action(arg: TP): TP
  def /[T <% TP](arg: T) = action(arg)
}

class Concrete3(str: String) extends Abstract3 {
  type TP = Concrete3
  override protected def action(arg: TP) = new TP("")
}

class Test3 {
  implicit def str2Concrete(s: String)(implicit num: Int) = new Concrete3(s)
  implicit val a = 1 
  val foo = "AA" / "BB" / "CC"
}
```

BTW, if we remove 'implicit num: Int', it will also compile fine.

```
abstract class Abstract3 {
  type TP
  protected def action(arg: TP): TP
  def *[T <% TP](arg: T) = action(arg)
}

class Concrete3(str: String) extends Abstract3 {
  type TP = Concrete3
  override protected def action(arg: TP) = new TP("")
}

class Test3 {
  implicit def str2Concrete(s: String) = new Concrete3(s)
  val foo = "AA" * "BB" * "CC"
}
```

Does * has higher precedence than implicit parameters, but / has a lower precedence? Or there is other reason that * does not work in this case?

Comment: If Daniel C. Sobrals's comment is correct, you can consider working around by naming your operator ":*". Doesn't look quite as nice, but does the job.

Answer (score 3):

I'm inclined to believe the problem lies with the fact that `*` is overloaded into `String` by  `Predef` (as in `"AA" * 5`), so, when you add your own `*` to it, you get an ambiguity in the conversion that makes Scala discard both of them.

With the conversions discarded, it's left with trying to find `*` on `String`, and it isn't there.

The problem with that idea is that `"AA" * 2` still works even with the import, and the conversion you added works without the implicit parameter. But I still think the answer lies that way.

Comment: -Yinfer-debug seems to say that the implicit int param breaks the conversion you get from the view T <% TP, which is considered after failing with the ambiguity.